# Django: recreating tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

Let me further clarify what I'm trying to do.  I've been developing my Django project on my machine.  I am also checking the code into a repository.  Currently I am the only developer, but other developers will join.  They will checkout the code from the repository and run it on their machine.  In order to simulate this scenario, I checked out my code into another directory and created a new database.  I updated settings.py for that checkout to use the new database.  When I do syncdb to recreate the tables, I get this error:

```
$ python -i manage.py syncdb
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'testproj.auth_user' doesn't exist")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Users\jpp\Documents\.virtualenvs\django-test\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Users\jpp\Documents\.virtualenvs\django-test\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Users\jpp\Documents\.virtualenvs\django-test\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\base.py", line 230, in run_from_argv
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Here's my database settings from phymyadmin:

```
User    Host        Type    Privileges      Grant   Action
root    localhost   global  ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes     Edit Privileges
```

and from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'testproj',             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',            # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                     # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Here is INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'helloworld',
)
```

Therefore, I suspect another developer to have this same problem.  This is a scenario that must have been addressed before, but I haven't been able to put together the right words for Google yet.

Comment: Please show full traceback, also your database settings (don't forget to change the password of database before showing it to us)

Comment: Keep HOST also as empty. Please show installed_apps of setting.py too

Comment: Ok, when I do that, I get this error: `OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")`.  However, I have been using HOST as 127.0.0.1 successfully for my other projects; localhost does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In the app I had created, helloworld, I had the following in `__init__.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if User.objects.filter(username="hello").count() == 0:
  user = User.objects.create_user(username='hello', password='hellotest')
  user.save()
```

When I commented out the entire if statement and ran syncdb, all the tables were recreated.  I guess before creating all of its own tables, `auth_user`, `auth_group`, etc. Django does whatever work is needed for the apps.  I'm not sure if this is a result of how python processes packages or a bug/limitation in Django.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create test tables, Django will do that automatically

[Test db documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database).

You can use a separate DB for testing if you wish, just add it to your [settings file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEST_NAME).  Make sure the DB is created but Django create the tables itself.

Comment: This is not a "test" database, but just another database I've created to test the scenario that when other people checkout my code, they have the tables ready for them when run the project.  I didn't have another machine to test this out on, so to simulate the scenario, I just checked out my code to another directory and changed the name of the database.  The database I created is empty, and it doesn't begin with "test;" I guess out of paranoia I changed the name when I posted this.